# How can sub paths be defined by omitting the parent path with React-Router-Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

So, let's say I have Profile page which renders different components according to the path.
For example:

`/profile/posts` renders Posts component inside Profile.

`/profile/comments` renders Comments component inside Profile.

I normally first render Profile page for `"/profile"` path and then inside it, render relevant Component according to the Routes mentioned above. What I would like to do is, omit the `"/profile"` part of the paths defined in Route components inside Profile and only keep the remaining part. How can that be done by not breaking the routing ?

See the comments in the code below:

```
// App.js

// ...

<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/profile">  // Profile page is rendered here
      <Profile />
    </Route>
</Switch>

// ...
```

```
// Profile.js

// ...

<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/profile/posts">  // I want to omit "/profile" part of the path.
      <Posts />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/profile/comments">  // I want to omit "/profile" part of the path.
      <Comments />
    </Route>
</Switch>
// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When nesting routes if you don't want to "duplicate" path details then you can  get them from the [match](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/match) object, specifically the `path` value for building nested routes.

Assuming `Profile` is a function component, use the [useRouteMatch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook to access the currently matched route's `path` value. If it is a class component then it will have to access route props to get `this.props.match`.

```
// Profile.js

const { path } = useRouteMatch();

// ...

<Switch>
  <Route path={`${path}/posts`}> 
    <Posts />
  </Route>
  <Route path={`${path}/comments`}>
    <Comments />
  </Route>
</Switch>

// ...
```

Here's a more in-depth [nested routing demo](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) from `react-router-dom.

Comment: What I would like to do is to not write the first part of path at all. I mean, if I'm already inside the Profile page, that means the path already has the "/profile" part. Otherwise, the Profile page wouldn't be rendered. That's said, I think writing the absolute path for the Components to be rendered in Profile page is unnecessarily repetitive. Is there a way to set their paths relative to the path of parent component ? Just "/posts" or just "/comments". Or maybe only a dot before the first slash, like "./posts"

Comment: @noiseymur Not in `react-router-dom` v5. In v6 this was a major change, and all links and routes can be declared relative to the parent route rendering them. Unfortunately in v5 the above is the standard pattern for handling nested routing. With this pattern you're really only specifying the last path segment, so for example if the absolute path was `"/parta/partb/partc/partd/etc/etc/targetsegment"`, then `\`${path}/targetsegment\`` could be all you'd need to specify.